# What to do about questions with no tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, migration

At the moment, there are eight questions with the "untagged" tag only. None are closed questions. At least one`*` was migrated from Economics SE beta, when it closed. I will go through those eight questions and add an appropriate tag or two now.

Is there any general reason this is happening, untagged questions? I never checked for prevalence rates on SE sites before.

`*EDIT`  It is possible that ALL eight of these untagged questions on money SE were migrated here. I am not certain, I will check now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why this can happen:

1. **Migration**: if a question is migrated and none of its tags exist on the destination site, it will be [untagged](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) there.
2. **Under-used tags**: if a tag has been used only once, and is more than 6 months old, [it will be automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags) - if that was the only tag on a question, then the question will be [untagged](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

When re-tagging these, focus on using tags that already exist. If it's necessary to create a new tag, try to find another question (or questions) where it applies and add it there too.

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the "untagged" tag for each of those eight questions.

- Four were migrated to Money SE from other SE sites. There were two from economics, but also one from quant SE (which was not shut down), and the other from stat SE (also alive and well).
- The other four were questions which were asked anywhere from three months to nearly two years ago.

I understand why the four recently migrated questions might be untagged, even though they should not have remained like this, as they were edited after migration, in most cases. But they may have slipped through, and that is certainly better than losing them if pressed for time, as the home beta sites were closing down.

It remains unclear to me why the **other four questions** were untagged for such a long time, as they had received plenty of page views, up votes, up voted and selected answers.

I'll post the URLs for each of the 8 questions, in case that helps. The key here is to avoid having this happen in the future. It only required 15-20 minutes to find and re-tag 8 questions. But it would be a problem if there were many more than that!

Comment: It is possible those four questions used redundant/duplicate tags that were mass-deleted early on, without having been mapped to another tag.  Thanks for taking care of it.